# Ada scale exceeds maximum value of 18

Tags: ada, alpine-linux, gnat

Dear Ada Enthusiasts,

```
type Long_Money_Type is delta 10.0**(-22) digits 38;
```

On The First Machine Ubuntu Linux 64 bit GNAT 8.3.0 this works.
On The Second Machine Alpine Linux 64 Bit GNAT 10.3.1 20211027 i get this error:

```
adx-lib-money.ads:14:29: scale exceeds maximum value of 18
adx-lib-money.ads:14:54: digits value out of range, maximum is 18
```

Is There an way to change the maximum value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem doesn’t occur with GCC 11 and later, so it looks as though you need to upgrade.

Comment: thank you Simon Wright GNAT 13.1.1 20230722 works..

Comment: Could this be related to the introduction of 128-bit Integers in GNAT, which happened just a few years ago?

Comment: @egilhh, `Long_Money_Type’Size` is 128 on macOS for GCC 11/12/13; `’Alignment` is 16. So 128-bit integer support is indeed needed.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Simon Wright's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76936455/230513), the Ada standard identifies certain [*Implementation-Defined Characteristics*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-M-2.html) in a way that "allows for certain machine dependences in a controlled manner". In particular,

> What combinations of *small*, *range*, and *digits* are supported for fixed point types. See [3.5.9(10)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-5-9.html#p10).

As a concrete example, the [GNAT 12.2 Reference Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gnat_rm/Implementation-Defined-Characteristics.html#Implementation-Defined-Characteristics) responds as follows:

> For a decimal fixed point type, on 32-bit platforms, the small must lie in 1.0E-18 .. 1.0E+18 and the digits in 1 .. 18. On 64-bit platforms, the small must lie in 1.0E-38 .. 1.0E+38 and the digits in 1 .. 38.

As a result, when searching for a suitable upgrade, verify that you choose the 64-bit version if both are available.